# How to create an index on CASE expression in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to create an index on CASE expression, as follows

```
CREATE TABLE test(i INT, j INT);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_index ON test(CASE WHEN i=1 THEN j END);
```

Getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
LINE 1: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_index ON test(CASE WHEN i=1 THEN j ...
                                               ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "CASE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 40
```

What am I doing wrong?

Postgres 9.5.2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add extra parentheses around the `CASE` expression:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_index 
  ON test ((CASE WHEN i=1 THEN j END)) ;
```

As the docs state in [`CREATE INDEX`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html):

> The key field(s) for the index are specified as column names, or alternatively as **expressions written in parentheses**.

---

Consider also using a filtered index, which is equivalent in terms of functionality but would be using less space, as it will be storing the `j` values only for rows with `i = 1` and not the (possibly millions) or the rest `NULL` values:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_index_2 
  ON test (j) WHERE i=1 ;
```

Comment: I'd +1 more for the filtered index suggestion.